# DB-Connections Class as a Singleton in Python

Tags: python, database, singleton

So there has been a lot of hating on singletons in python. I generally see that having a singleton is *usually* no good, but what about stuff that has side effects, like using/querying a Database? Why would I make a new instance for every simple query, when I could reuse a present connection already setup again? What would be a pythonic approach/alternative to this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally, you have some kind of object representing the thing that uses a database (e.g., an instance of `MyWebServer`), and you make the database connection a member of that object.

If you instead have all your logic inside some kind of function, make the connection local to that function. (This isn't too common in many other languages, but in Python, there are often good ways to wrap up multi-stage stateful work in a single generator function.)

If you have all the database stuff spread out all over the place, then just use a global variable instead of a singleton. Yes, globals are bad, but singletons are just as bad, and more complicated. There are a few cases where they're useful, but very rare. (That's not necessarily true for *other* languages, but it is for Python.) And the way to get rid of the global is to rethink you design. There's a good chance you're effectively using a module as a (singleton) object, and if you think it through, you can probably come up with a good class or function to wrap it up in.

---

Obviously just moving all of your globals into class attributes and `@classmethod`s is just giving you globals under a different namespace. But moving them into *instance* attributes and methods is a different story. That gives you an object you can pass around—and, if necessary, an object you can have 2 of (or maybe even 0 under some circumstances), attach a lock to, serialize, etc.

In many types of applications, you're still going to end up with a single instance of something—every Qt GUI app has exactly one `MyQApplication`, nearly every web server has exactly one `MyWebServer`, etc. No matter what you call it, that's effectively a singleton or global. And if you want to, you can just move everything into attributes of that god object.

But just because you *can* do so doesn't mean you *should*. You've still got function parameters, local variables, globals in each module, other (non-megalithic) classes with their own instance attributes, etc., and you should use whatever is appropriate for each value.

For example, say your `MyWebServer` creates a new `ClientConnection` instance for each new client that connects to you. You could make the connections write `MyWebServer.instance.db.execute` whenever they want to execute a SQL query… but you could also just pass `self.db` to the `ClientConnection` constructor, and each connection then just does `self.db.execute`. So, which one is better? Well, if you do it the latter way, it makes your code a lot easier to extend and refactor. If you want to load-balance across 4 databases, you only need to change code in one place (where the `MyWebServer` initializes each `ClientConnection`) instead of 100 (every time the `ClientConnection` accesses the database). If you want to convert your monolithic web app into a WSGI container, you don't have to change any of the `ClientConnection` code except maybe the constructor. And so on.

Comment: sort of 
app = class.webapp();
app.dbconn = class.dbconn()?
Is this really all that different to a singleton in the end?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an object oriented approach, then abamet's suggestion of attaching the database connection parameters as class attributes makes sense to me. The class can then establish a single database connection which all methods of the class refer to as `self.db_connection`, for example.

If you're not using an object oriented approach, a separate database connection module can provide a functional-style equivalent. Devote a module to establishing a database connection, and simply import that module everywhere you want to use it. Your code can then refer to the connection as `db.connection`, for example. Since modules are effectively singletons, and the module code is only run on the *first* import, you will be re-using the same database connection each time.

Comment: @JeffryFroman My Problem with using a module is that I like the idea of having sort of global but still singleton-class internal state.

Comment: How would you e.g. solve the "storing" of DB Connection parameters? Just having them in the same modules would be a little messy and having them in a general setting-like module would make the Database module strictly dependent on that one.